# How can I develop a Android App or Iphone app from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, android, ios

How can I develop a Android App or Iphone app from Visual Studio

Preferably the community edition of VS. 
Language of choice C#

What costs are involved and how would I go about getting this onto my phone?

Can I avoid putting it into the public app store?

Comment: I know that [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) is a pretty popular way of writing Android/iOS apps in C# and has a free [Starter Edition](https://store.xamarin.com/) to help get started, although I don't know the limitations.

Comment: I think the limitations look like the size of the app that may be developed

Comment: Who is your targetted user if it's not going in the store? If it's for personal use you do not necessarily need to put in the store, and even if you upload it, it can be hidden from public. With iOS you can also look at Enterprise program where only people with your approval can download the app from the store with no charge. You do however have to pay an annual fee to Apple.

Comment: @SASmith Myself and maybe one or two others dependant on the app I suppose wasn't really looking to do something commercial with it.
Thanks for your info, looks relevant

Comment: @Mdev depending on whether you are storing information locally you can just connect your device to the computer you're working on and install straight to it without ever needing to upload to a store. Be warned though, if you update the app, you risk losing all information that was previously on there. That is a disadvantage of not uploading to a store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer to that is http://xamarin.com/

You'll still need to have a Mac to debug iOS apps, but otherwise can code in Visual Studio on Windows.

With Android you can distribute very easily, for example via email. For iOS you would have to sign up for the enterprise app program, which means you *can't* sell apps on the store, but can distribute your app to internal devices.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

As for costs, they vary, just check the relevant web sites...

Comment: All seems pretty expensive

Xamarin does look the part but it does come with a heavy cost, but then that doesn't even get it onto the device?

Answer (score -1):

for android development i think eclipse is better choose. or you can use android studio. there are some plugins for visual studio that lets you write programs but it is not very efficient. eclipse is a standard environment for developing android apps.

Comment: Eclipse is definitely not a 'standard' environment for developing android apps in C#.